# Как подправить стиль кода в Clion

Tags: c, clion

Как сделать чтобы открытие блока ({) выполнялось автоматически с новой строки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Preferences
2. Editor
3. Code Style
4. C/C++
5. Wrapping and Braces
6. Braces placement

[image: Скриншот]